# pandas.Series.str.contains does not support line break or backslash in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I try to filter rows if `abbreviation` contains `'CS', 'DE', 'CM'` with `isin` and `str.contains` methods:

```
id,abbreviation,countries
1,CH,Switzerland
2,CZ,Czech Republic
3,CL,Chile
4,CM,Cameroon
5,CN,China
6,DJ,Djibouti
7,CR,Costa Rica
8,CS,Czech
9,DE,Germany
10,CY,Cyprus
```

When I don't use line break or backslash, both work smoothly and get same result:

```
mask1 = df['abbreviation'].str.contains('CS|DE|CM')
df[mask1]
mask2 = df['abbreviation'].isin(['CS', 'DE', 'CM'])
df[mask2]
```

Out:

```
   id abbreviation countries
3   4           CM  Cameroon
7   8           CS     Czech
8   9           DE   Germany
```

But I noticed when using backslash if there are too much values to filter, then `str.contains` fails to give the correct answer, but `isin` still works.

First option with backslash, only filter out `CS` contained rows:

```
mask1 = df['abbreviation'].str.contains('CS|\
        DE|\
        CM')
df[mask1]
```

Out:

```
   id abbreviation countries
7   8           CS     Czech
```

Second option with backslash generates correct result:

```
mask2 = df['abbreviation'].isin(['CS', \
          'DE', \
          'CM'])
df[mask2]
```

Out:

```
   id abbreviation countries
3   4           CM  Cameroon
7   8           CS     Czech
8   9           DE   Germany
```

Just wondering if anybody could give me advices how to solve this problem, if I want use break line for `str.contains`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.contains` attribute, (from documentation) the function signature is,

> `str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True)`

In Python, by default, the regex pattern (`pat` above) doesn't allow whitespace's / linebreaks.

When the pattern is inteneded to be more readable e.g. with comments, whitespaces (which should be ignored) etc., you have to provide the `re.VERBOSE` (doc [re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)) to the function call

So for your code, to use the intended pattern,

```py
In [52]: mask1 = df['abbreviation'].str.contains('CS|\    
    ...:         DE|\                                     
    ...:         CM', flags=re.VERBOSE)                   
    ...: df[mask1]

Out[52]:                                                  
   id abbreviation countries                              
3   4           CM  Cameroon                              
7   8           CS     Czech                              
8   9           DE   Germany
```